# returning matches from an unknown number of python lists

Tags: python

I have a list which contains 1-5 lists within it. I want to return only the values which appear in all the lists. I can easily create an exception for it there is only one list, but I can't think of a way round it when there are an multiple (unknown number of) lists. For example:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,7,8],[2,3,6,9],[1,2,5,7]]
```

would only return 2, because it's the only list item to appear in all the sub-lists

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can the lists contain duplicate values? Will the lists always be sorted?

Comment: The individual lists will not contain duplicates, and they won't be sorted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reduce(set.intersection, (set(x) for x in [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,7,8],[2,3,6,9],[1,2,5,7]]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`frozenset.intersection`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.intersection) (or `set.intersection` if you prefer):

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,7,8],[2,3,6,9],[1,2,5,7]]
>>> frozenset.intersection(*(frozenset(x) for x in l))
frozenset({2})
```

Add a call to list if you want the result as a list instead of a set.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this solution:

```
s = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,7,8],[2,3,6,9],[1,2,5,7]]

#flatten the list
flat = sum(s,[])

#only keep digits that appear a certain number of times (size of s)
filtered = filter(lambda x: flat.count(x) == len(s),flat)

# clear repeated values
list(set(filtered))
```

There are better ways to do this but this one is more explicit.

Comment: That... doesn't look any sort of explicit to me.

Comment: It is more explicit as it shows all the stages of filtering what chrism needs. I think the other answers do the job but are not so easy to understand.